# In FragmentPagerAdapters, should I use the FragmentManager with tags, or just a HashMap<Integer, Fragment>?

Tags: android

Currently, I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` whose `getItem()` method looks like this:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String fragmentName = makeFragmentName(R.id.rec_or_gallery_viewpager, position);
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
    Log.i("test_fragment_inst", fragment+"");
    if( position == 0 ) {
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = PicmixVideoGalleryChooserFragment.newInstance();
        }
    } else {
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = PicmixVideoRecordFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

I was thinking of changing it into this:

```
private Map<Integer, Fragment> fragmentMap;

public RecordOrGalleryFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fm = fm;
    fragmentMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();
}

...

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = fragmentMap.get(position);
    Log.i("test_fragment_inst", fragment+"");
    if( position == 0 ) {
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = PicmixVideoGalleryChooserFragment.newInstance();
            fragmentMap.put(position, fragment);
        }
    } else {
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = PicmixVideoRecordFragment.newInstance();
            fragmentMap.put(position, fragment);
        }
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Both do the same thing, basically, so will there be any performance improvements if I use the latter method, or should I just use the former method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the first variant, where you are using `FragmentManager` to access `Fragments` from the stack. It's possible to retrieve this fragment, if it was created before.

Ex. one screen doesn't have `Pager`, but few `Fragments` there, later you switched to screen two, where located your `FragmentPager`, and you are using previously created `Objects` of `Fragments`. However,  you can do the same with shared `Collection` of `Fragments` (what I don't recommend you to do).

**At the same time**, it's just common behavior to locate `Collection` of `Objects` in Adapter pattern implementation (in your case `FragmentPager` and his `Adapter`). And there is no performance difference of using one, or another solution.

One more note, you can even simplify `Map` to simple `Array`. And access to the `Fragment` `Objects` with their position indexes.

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, it is unsafe to use a `Map` to store and retrieve your fragments by position, because they may not survive configuration changes, and may throw unexpected errors such as `IllegalStateException` when you attempt to access them later.

Although having tags on fragments seems to be a better choice, but if your adapter is extending to `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, then it is a bad idea. In that case, you should not be returning old fragments in your `getItem`.

Here's a snippet of what `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem` does:

```
@NonNull
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (this.mCurTransaction == null) {
        this.mCurTransaction = this.mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    long itemId = this.getItemId(position);
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = this.mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        this.mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = this.getItem(position); // Get new instance of fragment
        this.mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }

    if (fragment != this.mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

It is absolutely clear that you should always return a new instance of fragment in `getItem`, or you will end up doing the same thing as `instantiateItem`. The `ViewPager` uses `instantiateItem` to decide how it should render pages, so if it needs a new one, your `getItem` better be returning a new instance.

Comment: Even when I only use 2 fragments in my `ViewPager`? Then again, I did notice that `getItem()` seems to be called when I scroll from the second page to the first.

Comment: Yes, even if there's only 2 fragments. Most importantly we should implement the adapter right, and avoid interfering the way ViewPager or FragmentPagerAdapter works because that's their design. The only reason I could think of why getItem was called when you scrolled back to first position: the fragment manager couldn't find the fragment, it could be destroyed for some lifecycle reason. Or maybe you can try increasing the offset page count.